# Infinitivsätze mit reflexiven Verben - Personalisierung

Tags: infinitive, reflexive

Mir (DaF-ler) wurde kürzlich von einem Deutschen eingewandt, dass der folgende Satz grammatikalisch fehlerhaft sei:

*Dass du [...], berechtigt **dich** nicht dazu, **dich** so zu verhalten.*

Laut meines Gegenübers hätte es eher

*Dass du [...], berechtigt nicht dazu, **dich/sich** so zu verhalten.*

heißen sollen. Wer hat in diesem Fall Recht? Oder kann es sein, dass die richtige Ausdrucksweise sogar eine andere ist, etwa:

*Dass du [...], berechtigt **dich** nicht dazu, **sich** so zu verhalten.*

oder irgendeine andere Kombination? Zu diesem Sachverhalt kann ich leider keinen Nachweis finden.

Comment: Alternativ *berechtigt nicht zu solchem / solch einem Verhalten*, denn wenn von Recht gesprochen wird, ist der Nominalstil nicht weit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vielleicht hat der Muttersprachler sich irgendwie selber verwirrt. Arg schwierig ist der Satz nicht. Das Verb *berechtigen* ist, wie die meisten Ableitungen mit *be-*, transitiv. Das Akkusativobjekt entfällt allerdings gerne, wenn aus dem Kontext klar ist, wer berechtigt wird (wie z.B. *die Abiturienten* im folgenden Beispiel).

> Das Abitur berechtigt zum Studium.

Da man sich in der Regel nicht selbst berechtigt, ist das Akkusativobjekt, sofern vorhanden, nicht reflexiv. Im Ausgangsbeispiel ist das Subjekt ein Satz, der einen Sachverhalt bezeichnet, das Akkusativobjekt eine Person; es liegt also keine Reflexivität vor. Ein paralleles Beispiel wäre:

> **Die Tatsache, dass Behörden falsch informiert worden sind,** berechtigt **uns** alle dazu, von einem echten Skandal zu sprechen. *(Protokoll der Sitzung des Parlaments Bayerischer Landtag am 29.01.2002)*

Der Aufbau der eingebetteten Infinitivkonstruktion ist unabhängig vom Matrixsatz. *Sich auf eine Weise verhalten* ist ein echt reflexives Verb. Das verstandene Subjekt der Infinitivkonstruktion im Ausgangsbeispiel ist *du*, bezogen auf *dich* im Matrixsatz, weshalb in der Infinitivkonstruktion ebenfalls *dich* auftaucht.

Man könnte das Ausgangsbeispiel variieren:

> Diese Tatsache berechtigt **Sie** nicht dazu, **sich** so zu verhalten.
>   Diese Tatsache berechtigt **euch** nicht dazu, **euch** so zu verhalten.
>   Diese Tatsache berechtigt **uns** nicht dazu, **uns** so zu verhalten.

Wenn man allerdings das Akkusativobjekt im Matrixsatz streicht, kann in der Infinitivkonstruktion kein *dich* mehr auftauchen, da man das ausgelassene Akkusativobjekt dann indefinit als als *jemand* (bzw. *niemand*) interpretiert, wozu nur *sich* (3. Person Singular) paßt.

> Diese Tatsache berechtigt **niemanden** dazu, **sich** so zu verhalten.
>   Diese Tatsache berechtigt nicht dazu, **sich** so zu verhalten.

Ausgeschlossen sind demnach:

> *Diese Tatsache berechtigt nicht dazu, **dich** so zu verhalten.
>   *Diese Tatsache berechtigt **dich** nicht dazu, **sich** so zu verhalten.

Comment: ginge " Diese Tatsache berechtigt euch nicht dazu, so zu verhalten." ?

Comment: @Dan Nein, *sich so verhalten* ist "echt reflexiv", das Reflexivobjekt kann nicht weggelassen werden. Ähnlich: *sich verbeugen, erkälten*. Optionales *sich* gibt es (ausnahmsweise?) bei *(sich) irren*.

Comment: naja, schon klar. Mir ging es hier eher darum, ob hier eine Ellipse vorkommen kann, d.h. die Weglassung vom aus dem Kontext leicht zu erschließbaren Wort.

Comment: @Dan Das ist ja das Verblüffende an den echt reflexiven Verben, daß das reflexive Objekt nichts zur Bedeutung beiträgt und trotzdem stehen muß.